# Remove google analytics from drupal site

Tags: drupal, google-analytics

After exclude google analytics from drupal code the module still there,

How to remove google analytics module from drupal site completely ?

Comment: Disable, uninstall, delete.

Comment: In that exact order.

Answer (score 1):

@leymannx is correct in his comment on your question. The correct order is to disable the module, uninstall it, and then delete it from your file system. However, from your question I gather that the module has already been removed from your file system. From this point, you want to delete references to it from your database.

*Please note: this is a dangerous way to proceed and if you can simply restore your file system and follow the process @leymannx laid out, you should do so.*

The process is outlined in [this community doc](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215). But the basic idea is to run one of these commands on your database:

Drupal 7: `DELETE from system where type = 'module' AND name = 'google_analytics';`

Drupal 8: `DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='google_analytics';`

Then dump your cache and the module should be completely gone.